# Prevent logged in users from seeing other registered users information

Tags: users

I'm using Drupal 8 and I have a security requirement to prevent authenticated users from seeing other authenticated users' profiles.

I have a view which customizes the user profile page of each authenticated user. Each logged in user can see their own profile by accessing the path /user-profile/userId.

Now if the user decided to randomly change the userId in the URL, they cannot access other users' profiles, since, in the view I have set the 'Filter Criteria' to current user. Which works perfectly.

However, if a user decided to randomly change the userId in the path /user/userId they will have access to other users information. What I need to do is to prevent them from accessing /user/userId.

It's important to mention that the users are free to change their own information using the URL /user/userId/edit

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should change the permission for authenticated users.

Go to `admin/people/permissions` and under **user** permissions dissallow authenticated users to `View user information`

[image]

Comment: thank you, I hate how trivial that was, cheers